# Discrepancy in inferential tests using metafor

Tags: r, meta-analysis, metafor

I am running analyses using metafor, looking at different scores between two groups. All of these are using raw mean differences (so `rma(yi = MEAN_DIFFERENCES, sei = STANDARD_ERRORS)`. A co-author suggested we also provide standardized mean differences, so I computed means, SDs, and group Ns for each analysis and passed them in (so `rma(m1i=MEANS_EXPERIMENTAL, m2i=MEANS_CONTROL, sd1i=SDS_EXPERIMENTAL, sd2i=SDS_CONTROL, n1i=NS_EXPERIMENTAL, n2i=NS_CONTROL, measure="SMD")`).

Results passed an initial sanity check, but I noticed that the inferential stats (`zval` and `pval`) are inconsistent with what I obtained using the mean differences (in one instance this resulted in a p-value above alpha using the SMD analysis but below it using the MD analysis).

Does this indicate some underlying issue, or am I misunderstanding how `rma.uni` computes model results? Is there a more elegant way of doing this (e.g., computing a SMD and confidence intervals from a model that used MDs)?

EDIT: example output from one of the MD analyses...

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 23; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0604 (SE = 0.0248)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.2457
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   81.86%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  5.51

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 22) = 80.6150, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub      
 -0.2249  0.0606  -3.7096  0.0002  -0.3437  -0.1061  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And the same original variables, but SMD...

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 23; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0498 (SE = 0.0220)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.2232
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   72.89%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  3.69

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 22) = 65.6464, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub      
 -0.2194  0.0568  -3.8612  0.0001  -0.3308  -0.1081  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Why do you think that the analysis with mean differences ought to be the same as that with standardized mean differences?

Comment: @PeterFlom Obviously the estimate, CIs, etc. will be different (that's the point), but this is just representing the same data using standardized values rather than raw scores. Looking at the formula for Hedge's g (what metafor uses for SMDs), it seems it should result in the same z-score as the MD analysis, which uses mean differences and standard errors? Again, maybe I am misunderstanding how `rma` works.

Comment: To clarify: I'm just thinking of the information embedded in both the Hedge's g formula and standard errors + mean differences.

Comment: Try plotting the mean differences against the standardised ones and see if you get a straight line. If you want to know what rma.uni() actually does the code is freely available.

Comment: @mdewey definitely not a straight line. Pearson's correlation between the two is ~.8. That function and dependencies is huge and I don't have a lot of time to do a deep dive into the source right now.

Answer (score 1):

(I'd be more confident in my answer if you included some output).

The first approach is using the mean difference - this is appropriate when all your outcomes are using the same scale. In this way you can interpret a standard deviation difference as equivalent in every measure. A 10 point increase in the outcome (bone density, PHQ-9, mobility score) means the same thing. This is generally considered the best approach, when you can use it, which is rare.

The second approach is using the standardized mean difference. You use this when different studies have measured the outcome on different scales and you can't easily convert between them. One study used the PHQ-9, so a change of 5 points has one meaning, another study used the BDI, so a change of 5 points has a different meaning. You can't average these two, so you standardize and then you are talking about the average change in standard deviations.

The problem with the second approach is that different populations might have different standard deviations. Weight in adults might have a very different SD depending on the population that you sampled from - so a 1 kg difference in weight gets a different SMD.  But if someone measured difference in kg, someone else measured difference in waist size, and someone else measured difference in BMI, you don't really have a choice.

The second approach is (an order of magnitude or two) more common, at least in my experience.